# dpkg error while installing heroku on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dpkg, dependencies, heroku

I am trying to install heroku toolbelt on mu ubuntu 14.04

I tried so many things including an answer from here itself. It was to run the following command

`wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh`

Yet I am still getting the following error:

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
dpkg: error processing package heroku (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of heroku-toolbelt:
 heroku-toolbelt depends on heroku (= 3.99.4); however:
  Package heroku is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package heroku-toolbelt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 heroku
 heroku-toolbelt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You misread the instructions on their webpage - the `wget...` command applies to Ubuntu 12 and below.

For your system, Ubuntu 14.04 please use the other command specified:

`sudo snap install heroku`

Comment: I tried that too and I got `sudo: snap: command not found`

Comment: You will need to install it, and reboot `sudo apt install snapd`, as referenced [http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/install-snap-apps-ubuntu-14-04](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/install-snap-apps-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: After I did `sudo apt install snapd` , i again tried to install heroku by doing `sudo snap install heroku` and I got following error    `error: cannot install "heroku": snap not found`

Comment: Then you may need to contact the heroku maintainers.   You  *could* try the 'standalone' installation, but given that the package seems to be poorly maintained, I do not know that this would work.